# std::ofstream : Writing to a file using append and out flags

Tags: c++, stl, ofstream

Below is a simple class which attempts to write an integer to a file. The mode of writing the file is to append characters at the end of the file (In this mode, file should be created if it doesn't exist)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class TestFileStream
{
private:

    std::ofstream* _myFileStream;
    bool isFileOpen;

public:

    TestFileStream():isFileOpen(false)
    {
        _myFileStream = new std::ofstream("TestFile.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app );
        isFileOpen = _myFileStream->is_open();

        if( !isFileOpen  )
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to open log file" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Good State: " << _myFileStream->good() <<std::endl;
            std::cout << "Eof State: " << _myFileStream->eof() <<std::endl;
            std::cout << "Fail State: " << _myFileStream->fail() <<std::endl;
            std::cout << "Bad State: " << _myFileStream->bad() <<std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Opened log file" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~TestFileStream()
    {
        _myFileStream->close();
        delete _myFileStream;
        _myFileStream = nullptr;
    }

    void WriteFile( unsigned number )
    {
        if ( isFileOpen )
        {
            (*_myFileStream) << "Number: " << number << std::endl;
        }
    }       
};

int main() 
{
    // Number of iterations can be multiple.
    // For testing purpose, only 1 loop iteration executes
    for( unsigned iter = 1; iter != 2; ++iter )
    {
     TestFileStream fileWriteObj;
     fileWriteObj.WriteFile( 100+iter );
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the above code, I get following log output:

```
Unable to open log file
Good State: 0
Eof State: 0
Fail State: 1
Bad State: 0
```

This seems like trivial task, but I am not able to find out whats causing the failure. Note that this question is most likely related to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970420/ofstream-doesnt-open-or-write-to-files)

Comment: Why do you use `new` (unrelated) ? What are your permissions in the current directory ?

Comment: Works for me. Is it about permissions maybe?

Comment: My actual code is too big to reproduce here. , so I wrote this example on ideone.com. Maybe something to do with file write permissions on ideone. In my actual code, I have appx 50K loop iterations. And I am logging lots of data per loop iteration. The file is created and does gets written but only for some iterations..say 550...but for the remaining iterations my code keeps showing the error "Unable to open log file". I am clueless on why this is happening.

Comment: No need to dynamic allocate the stream, or use out flag (ofstream is out by default) and no need to close the file before deleting - it happens automatically. Be aware writing endl intead of "\n" to a file is slower.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Yes, I know about redundant out flag and that heap allocation is not required. Instead my TestFileStream object should be created on heap. I didn't knew about the file closing part(thanks for that). I am writing endl only to flush the stream.

Comment: @nurabha If the code you posted doesn't show the problem, you posted the wrong code. If you don't know which code to post, do more research.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: I have no other way to reproduce the error but to write a sample code that reflects my actual code in a simple way

Comment: In my actual code, the state of the stream when unable to log is as follows: GOOD=0, EOF=0, FAIL=1,BAD=0. I am wondering why FAIL flag is set

Comment: @nurabha Yeah, but this code works. Where is the problem? Is it about multithreading? HDD capacity? I really don't know because I get `Opened log file` when I execute the code above. I can only guess.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: Well, the drive on which my code executes has 52 GB free. Thats not issue. The code is running in single thread at the moment (thanks for pointing of thread-safety issue)

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize the comments, there is nothing wrong about the code you posted (apart from the rather unconventional new ostream ;) )

Note however that opening files may fail for a number of reasons (Permissions, file in use, disk unavailable, the file does not exist, the file exists...). That is why you must always test it.

If you tried to run the above code in an online emulator, then chances are file IO is disabled. Which would explain why you get that the streams fail-bit is set.

Comment: Actually I am doing following sequence of operations inside a loop (50K times): "opening a file, appending some data to it and closing the file". Maybe repeatedly opening and closing the file is causing the problem of FAIL state getting state after some 500 odd iterations. Instead, I think I should be opening the file before entering the loop, and inside the loop I should append data to the file and finally I should  close the file outside the loop. Maybe that could fix the problem.

Comment: Whether it fixes the problem or not, you *should* definitely do that. :)